# How to Inject ManagedBeans in JSF2.0

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, annotations, jsf-2

I have got Controller-ManagedBeans and Model-ManagedBeans (like MVC-Pattern).

Here my Controller:

```
   @ManagedBean
   @RequestScoped
    public class ProjectController {

 private ProjectData projectBean;   //The Model-ManagedBean (see below)!
 private IProjectService projectService;    //My Service-Layer

 public ProjectController(){
  init();
 }

 private void init(){
  projectBean = new ProjectData();
  projectService = new ProjectService();
 }

 public String saveProject() {
  projectService.addProject(projectBean.getProjectDTO());

  return ("");
 }
    }
```

...and her you can see my model, which gets its values out of a facelet...

```
@ManagedBean(name="ProjectData")
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectData {

 private ProjectDTO projectDTO;

 public ProjectData(){
  projectDTO = new ProjectDTO();
 }

 public ProjectDTO getProjectDTO() {
  return projectDTO;
 }

 public void setProjectDTO(ProjectDTO projectDTO) {
  this.projectDTO = projectDTO;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
  return projectDTO.getTitle();
 }

 public void setTitle(String title) {
  projectDTO.setTitle(title);
 }
}
```

My problem is now that it doesn't work. I think I need to inject the dependency between those two classes. But how? Is there a JSF-pro that can help me.
I would like to use annotations.
Thanks

---

### Update after BalusC's post

I changed my code a little bit, but it still doesn't work. Any further advice, please.

```
@ManagedBean(name="projectData")
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectData {
```

...

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{projectData}")
private ProjectData projectData;
```

The error `com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException` says that the controller bean can not be created because projectData (the model-bean) is not found..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys I have found the answer:

there are missing get and set methods in my controller:

```
/*
 * Getter and Setter
 */
public ProjectData getProjectData() {
    return projectData;
}

public void setProjectData(ProjectData projectData) {
    this.projectData = projectData;
}
```

[Reference](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=66080)

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{ProjectData}")
private ProjectData projectBean
```

---

That said, the normal practice is to start instance names with a lowercase. You also don't do in real

```
ProjectData ProjectData = new ProjectData();
```

but rather

```
ProjectData projectData = new ProjectData();
```

If you omit the `(name="ProjectData")` from the `@ManagedBean`, then it will automatically default to `projectData`.

---

As per your update:

> The error `com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException`  says that the controller bean can not be created because projectData (the model-bean) is not found.

It's actually more telling that **property** projectData cannot be found. The property is not writable. In other words, the setter is missing. In the future please don't rephrase error messages and just copypaste them.

Comment: What do you mean with that? I started all the instances with a lowercase. Do you want me to start with an uppercase? Sry, it's not clear to me...Sven

Comment: Just start instance names with lower case, or omit the `(name="XXX")`. This is not the cause of your problem, it's just a practice.

Comment: all right master BalusC, I wonder if I can book you like a personal coach ;-)